# Rabbitmq erlang client build failed due to file paths problems?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, ejabberd, mnesia

I have been able to build rabbitmq server on ubuntu linux. It came already prepackaged and on making, it is able to start as a service. When i got the client source, i failed to make because it appeared like it needed a folder called ./deps/rabbitmq-server. Analysing the code, i find that the author of the client was accessing the same header files as are found in the server, using include_lib("path to rabbit.hrl e.t.c") in his header file called "amqp_client.hrl". I then decided to add rabbitmq_server in the lib dir of erlang so as its paths are automatically added on start up of the vm. But still this didnot help. There is also another folder which the client references called "rabbit_common" for an include folder he assumes would contain all the .hrl files there. Please assist me in building both the client and server on my ubuntu server, for testing.

Also, if anyone has used RabbitMQ server for IMs, please provide some benchmarks and/or your findings on its throughput, speed and number of users. How can it be compared to ejabberd?. How can one create AJAX/Jquery/Javascript clients for Web functionality?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you had made some progress as far as RabbitMQ and ejabberd are concerned.

Below is a link to an interesting discussion that might be of help.
http://old.nabble.com/AMPQ-vs-XMPP-and-RabbitMQ-vs-ejabberd-td17587109.html